# Grab certain text as soon as it appears - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, webcam

I have an app which scans a QR Code from a webcam. Now this scanner gets it from a live feed, no capture image. This in a way is great for what i want, less human interaction, however it has presented a problem for me.

When the QR Code is scanned it is presents the URL/text in a textbox but as soon as i removed the QR code from the webcam the text disappears.

Is there anyway of grabbing the text from the textbox depending on what it is? i want it to be pulled if the QR code text has "Job x" in it. Any ideas to get that text before i remove the qr code from the webcam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just asking how to add a change-handler to an ?

```
document.getElementById('myInput').onchange = function() {
    console.log(this.value);
};
```

This assumes that the code responsible for setting your  text is triggered an `onchange` event. (It won't happen by default unless the field receives focus/blur.)

Comment: something like that yes :) is it possible to do on change but only when text consists of the word "Job x" ? sorry if im a bit noobish here, im only a few days old to javascript ha :)

Comment: No problem. Sure, if you want to only react when the text contains a certain value, then you can use `this.value.match(/^Job/)`